# How to optimise pyspark approxSimilarityJoin for 2 very large data frames

Tags: join, pyspark, similarity, approximate

I want to join two huge data frame based on their similarity. I tried using approxsimilarityjoin. However the task gets stuck after some time and eventually fails.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it:

1. Increase the cluster size
2. Use Broadcast join if one of the dataset is a lot smaller than the other
3. Use blocking techniques
4. Use Deltalakes if that options is available

Comment: Thanks Rob. I am still confused since I am using spark for the first time. What do you mean by blocking techniques. Also, I cannot use broadcast join as both data frames are huge.